# Trying to sumproduct parts to their final assembly in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have two tables (will be dynamic data) that I was looking to reference for output on a third table, image of all three below:

[Updated Image with example of output I am lookign for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P42yt.png)

The first table shows a forecast of unit sales of Final Products A-I (y axis) broken out by expected month that they will need to be assembled (x Axis).

The second table would be a 2-D array indicating what sub-parts are needed to build the final products in the first table. Sub parts on the x axis and Final Product on the y axis. (example: Final Product A needs 10 parts of sub part A and 5 parts of sub part B etc.)

I would like to find a way to sum the total sub-parts needed by month to build the forecasted Final Products in a third table (sub parts on the y axis and month required on the x axis). I have tried to use SUMPRODUCT methods but am unable to figure out a realistic solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you add the Subpart columns to the Final Product Forecast table and do a VLOOKUP to get the qty/product? Then you can add at the bottom a total row of SUMPRODUCT these columns and the final product qty/month columns.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó thank you for the input, but I am not sure it will work because the Subpart table will be a dynamic pivot table. I believe the only option is to find a formula that multiplies every sub part requirement per final parts needed for a given month, and that should be a sumproduct variant of some sort? Please let me know if I am missing your point, I am very desperate to figure out how to do this. Thank you!

Comment: No, you did not miss my point, I thought the BOM is not changing unexpectedly. If this is the case, then do the other way round as you say, put the month columns on the sheet where the Subparts are , VLOOKUP the qty, and then you can SUMPRODUCT. Please show what you have tried and update your question, also with the info how the tables are produced, otherwise people would assume those are static structures.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in cell B17:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET($B$4,,MATCH(B$16,$B$3:$M$3,0)-1,COUNTIF($O:$O,"Final*"),)*OFFSET($P$4,,MATCH($A17,$P$3:$Q$3,0)-1,COUNTIF($O:$O,"Final*"),))
```

Maybe the countif($O:$O,"Final*") part can be replaced by 9, but if you get more different Final Parts it will grow along.

You can drag the formula to the other cells.